# Can we access GIT_BRANCH variable in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am creating pipeline where I want to deploy my application on different environments(devlopment, qa, production) according to the branches.
for example : If branch is development we want to deploy it on development environment ,If branch is master we want to deploy it on production.
for this I am trying to get value of GIT_BRANCH but it is returning 'null' .

Is GIT_BRANCH variable compatible with jenkins pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You should have the https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin that will give you GIT_BRANCH as an environment variable which you can later use in your scripts.

Comment: yes vineeth ,I have git plugin . But issue is it  'GIT_BRANCH' variable returning null value